# Ionic Cordova build ios Fail

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, cordova, ionic2

Hey I am trying to build my ionic cordova app for ios.
When I run: 
ionic cordova build ios --release
My build fails

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC 
/Users/blakemabe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-
fmpngedelpajbadyfzqoksexavsk/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Release-
iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirebasePlugin.o 
MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/FirebasePlugin.m normal i386 
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
(node:12626) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 65 for 
command: xcodebuild with args: -
xcconfig,/Users/blakemabe/Desktop/drive/drive_ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/b
uild-release.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-
configuration,Release,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS 
Simulator,name=iPhone 6s 
Plus,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/blakemabe/Desktop/drive/drive_ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/blakemabe/Desktop/drive/drive_ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
(node:12626) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12626) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: There might be an error message preceding this one. The solution might be there...

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to having both `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` and the newer `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`.

I fixed if by doing

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

Then I could run again:

```
ionic cordova run ios
```